# Configure Visual Studio to break when any managed code is hit

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am spinning up an ASP.NET website from Visual Studio for debugging purposes. I am unsure of the entry point for a given action, so I would like VS to break as soon as any managed code it hit (thus showing me the entry point!). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to launch the app using F10 rather than F5. This will show you the starting point of the web app bootstrapping process. Another thing you can do is to let the app start as usual (F5) and then detach from the browser and pause the app before clicking anything in the browser.

Unfortunately it will stop deeply in the ASP plumbing code. To get to the app code will still take some digging

Answer (score 0):

You can place breaking points on selected patrs of your code